# Why turning off kwin compositor fixed my different refresh rates problem?

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde, kwin

Kubuntu X11 (I think) x64 RTX 2080 i9 9900k.

So I have 3 monitors @ 60hz and 1 @ 240hz, Everyone 1080p.

I always had the problem that the refresh rate was limited by the most weak monitor, this is 60hz in the 240hz monitor.

I found in a forum that if I turn off kwin this could be resolved.

So I have some questions.

What is KWin compositor and why turning off with shift+alt+F12 fixed my desktop different refresh rate problem? How can I keep this disabled after every reboot? Any advice about different refresh rate monitor management?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing_window_manager) should explain it better than I could. As far as the last question, you need to set up a custom **mode** with `xrandr`. Read the man_page. You may need to add the command to the bash rc file for persistence, but I wouldn't think it would be necessary. You will just need to try it and see if it stays across reboots.

Comment: Disabling the compositor at startup in monitors isn't activating anymore, thanks

Comment: If you can't figure it out, you can use `xrandr auto` or `xrandr preferred` to set it back to what it was to begin with. Did you not read the manual? That is on you. Xrandr lets you explicitly set the refresh rate on a per-monitor basis. It can't get any more straight forward than that...

Comment: I have the exact same setup (3@~60, 1@240) and I used `xrandr` without issue, so I know it works.